# Improving the translation of googletrans

Tags: python, python-3.x, translation, google-translate

Im new to python and programming  and I would like o translate a file containing hundreds of thousands of Greek cities from english to greek.

After some research I found the googletrans module and decided to use that due to its simplicity.

However due to the enormous amount of cities alot of the translations appear to be off.

My initial thought was to manually "translate" the cities that were translated incorrectly, by substituing the english letters with their greek counterparts but again there were alot of wrong translations.

Any advice as to how to overcome this problem?
Is it even possible to do so?
Is there any better module?
Is googletrans legal?

Thanks alot in advance and happy new year to everyone!!

Comment: Google Translate isn't the only publicly available translator. By legal, I assume you mean the best?

Comment: Indeed you are right but, doesn't the fact that google translate gets around 40% of the translations wrong due to the hundreds of thousands of city names mean that, other translators won't have 100% accurate results too?

Comment: By "legal"  I was referring to the python module as in a few sites ,including this one, I've read threads where people state ,that you actually have to pay in order to use google translate's servers in your python programmes.

Comment: Translators are built from some manual human input. Google doesn't have to share it's database with other engines. And if you have to pay, then the API would require you to input a key. You can *try it free* https://cloud.google.com/translate/

Comment: Oh thanks alot! it seems like I misunderstood the situation...